# Set type to variable from method with parameter of variable type

Tags: generics, methods, dynamic, parameters, properties

Basically, I have a class Text with a set of properties.

I want to fill these in with properties from other classes.

I could use Method Overloading, but since I am basically doing the exact same thing multiple times, it seemed cleaner to do it in one method.

What I have and works:

```
private Text SetText(Book book)
{
 return new Text{
  Media = book.GetType().ToString();
  Pages = book.Pages,
  Words = book.Words,
}
private Text SetText(Letter letter)
{
 return new Text{
  Media = letter.GetType().ToString();
  Pages = letter.Pages,
  Words = letter.Words,
}
```

Now is there a way to a) have 1 method that works both for Book and Letter and b) to automatically fill in Pages and Words, keeping in mind that both Letter and Book also have other properties.

So something like

```
private Text SetText<T>(T data)
{
 return new Text
  {
   Media = data.GetType().ToString(),
   Pages = data.Pages,
   Words = data.Words,
  }
}
```

If question a could get answered that would help me out a ton.

If question b could get answered that would be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 0):

"dynamic" type is what is needed.

```
private Text GetText(object data)
    {
     dynamic objectData = Convert.ChangeType(data, data.GetType());
     return new Text
      {
       Media = objectData.GetType().Name,
       Pages = objectData.Pages,
       Words = objectData.Words,
      }
    }
```

This works since it only runs at runtime and as such allows for dynamic typing.